# How to reconfigure LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean in test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

If I have a programmatically managed LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, like with a @Bean-annotated method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManager",
  transactionManagerRef = "myTransactionManager",
  basePackages = {"com.mycompany.my.repository"}
)
public class MyDbConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mcEntityManager() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      //some production config here
      return em;
    }
}
```

How do I add this little JPA property only to be used for integration testing, ideally via something like a listener below (in the test classpath)

```
public class AfterAllBeansCreatedListener {

    @Autowired
    private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em

    @PostConstruct
    private void reconfigure() {
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = em.getJpaPropertyMap()
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    }
}
```

Currently, I am using another @Bean-annotated method producing LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean in a nested @TestConfiguration, but this means that I need to duplicate all the other creation logic for that bean, which is of course pure evil.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and simple solution is to create a Map of properties within the mcEntityManager() method like so

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManager",
transactionManagerRef = "myTransactionManager",
basePackages = {"com.mycompany.my.repository"}
)
public class MyDbConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mcEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = em.getJpaPropertyMap()
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return em;
    }
}
```

If you need different JpaProperty map values per env, you'd move the property map creatation to it's own Profile specific methods, like

```
@Bean
@Profile("dev)
public Map<String,Object> getMyJpaPropertyMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    properties.put("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults",false);
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation",true);
}

@Bean
@Profile("prod)
public Map<String,Object> getMyJpaPropertyMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    properties.put("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults",true);
}
```

and the mcEntityManager() method is updated to

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mcEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(getMyJpaPropertyMap());
    return em;
}
```

Comment: you problably need to inject the jpaPropertyMap. Otherwise you would get method signature clash at compile time

Answer (score 0):

**Sample code:**

```
public class LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBeanProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        // You can override or extend Hibernate configuration here
        if (bean instanceof LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean && factoryBean.getJpaVendorAdapter() instanceof HibernateJpaVendorAdapter) {
            factoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap()
                    .put(key, value);
        }
        return bean;
    }

}
```